# Nearest point of MultiPoint to another Point, over a LineString

Tags: postgis, point, distance, line

I need to calculate the distance between some points on a line (*LineString*), using PostGIS, to find the nearest over a set of *MultiPoint*.

I know there is a function *ST_Distance()*, but this one returns a distance as the crow flies, with no possibility to take a path into account.

The problem is : "which of A or B is the nearest of S ?"

Here is a little drawing, for a better explanation :

[image: Drawing]

Is there an alternative to ST_Distance() ?

---

I have already read [Getting distance between two points over linestring using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/182113/115), but unfortunately, it doesn't give a complete reply : I have a MultiPoint feature.

The solution given wasn't succesfull, but I guess it may just need an adaptation ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostGIS get the distance between two points over a linestring](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182113/postgis-get-the-distance-between-two-points-over-a-linestring)

Comment: Well, not really : the example given uses "Point" features, I unfortunately need "MultiPoint".

Comment: What did you try when it "wasn't successful"?

Comment: You could first split the `MultiPoint` into a set of `Point`s, find the distance to each, order the result and take the first.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick adaptation of the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/182145/36484) for this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/182113/36484).  The additional part that you need is [ST_Dump](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html)

```
SELECT
    ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(
        line,
        ST_LineLocatePoint(line, s),
        ST_LineLocatePoint(line, (ST_Dump(p)).geom)))
    ,(ST_Dump(p)).path[1] ind
FROM (
  SELECT
    'LINESTRING(0 0, 10 0, 10 5, 0 5)'::geometry line,
    'POINT(1 0)'::geometry s,
    'MULTIPOINT(1 5, 10 3, 8 5)'::geometry p
) data
ORDER BY 1;
```