# Shortest paths between points over multiple linestrings

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, shortest-path, pgr-dijkstra

I'd like to calculate the distance between one and multiple other points along a network of LineStrings. I'm aware of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182113) question which calculates the distance on a substring of a LineString, but not over multiple ones.

**Q** How can I calculate the distances along the network from the Point `SITE1` to the two Points `WWTP1` and `WWTP2` in the example data below? Is this something for pgRouting? Note, I'm not looking for the Euclidean distance.

**Data**

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS river;
CREATE TABLE river (gid varchar, geom geometry);
INSERT INTO river VALUES
    ('ID1', 'LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2, 2 3, 4 3)'),
    ('ID2', 'LINESTRING(4 3, 5 6, 6 8)'),
    ('ID3', 'LINESTRING(6 8, 8 4, 9 5)'),
    ('ID4', 'LINESTRING(2 3, 1 4)'),
    ('ID5', 'LINESTRING(1 4, 1 5, 0 4, -1 1)'),
    ('ID6', 'LINESTRING(-1 1, -3 2)');
    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS site;
CREATE TABLE site (gid varchar, geom geometry);
INSERT INTO site VALUES
    ('SITE1', 'POINT(1 1)');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wwtp;
CREATE TABLE wwtp (gid varchar, geom geometry);
INSERT INTO wwtp VALUES
    ('WWTP1', 'POINT(0 4)'),
    ('WWTP2', 'POINT(8 4)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer if you want to solve the [One-to-Many](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.1/en/pgr_dijkstra.html#one-to-many) situation, as I originally intended. It's a minor modification of the last code chunk of @timothy-dalton's (+1) answer. The most important part is that you pass the target id's as an array `SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a.id)`.

```sql
WITH
start_point AS (
    SELECT geom
    FROM site
),
destination_point AS (
    SELECT gid, geom
    FROM wwtp
    WHERE gid IN ('WWTP1', 'WWTP2')
),
dijkstra AS (
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT gid as id, source, target, ST_Length(geom) AS cost FROM river_segments',
        -- finding the source node spatially
        (SELECT a.id
         FROM river_segments_vertices_pgr a, start_point b
         ORDER BY a.the_geom <-> b.geom LIMIT 1),
        -- finding all targets node spatially
        (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a.id)
         FROM river_segments_vertices_pgr a, destination_point b
         WHERE ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.geom)),
        false
    )
),
route_geom AS (
    SELECT
        dijkstra.seq,
        dijkstra.cost,
        dijkstra.end_vid,
    CASE
        WHEN dijkstra.node = river_segments.source THEN geom
        ELSE ST_Reverse(geom)
    END AS route_geom
    FROM dijkstra
    LEFT JOIN river_segments ON (edge = gid)
    ORDER BY seq
),
dist_geom AS (
    SELECT
        rou.end_vid,
        ST_AsText(ST_Collect(route_geom)) wkt,
        ST_Length(ST_Collect(route_geom)) length,
        ST_Collect(route_geom) geom
    FROM route_geom rou
    GROUP BY rou.end_vid
)
SELECT wwt.gid, dis.*
FROM dist_geom dis
LEFT JOIN wwtp wwt ON ST_Intersects(dis.geom, wwt.geom)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As you already pointed out, this indeed can be solved with `pgRouting` and will have to be added to your database [as an extension](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.1/en/pgRouting-installation.html). You will have to do some preparations with the data to get it going.

First of all you will have to break the linestrings into individual segments in order to build a sound topology:

```
-- https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/breaking-linestring-into-segments.html
CREATE TABLE river_segments AS
WITH 
dumps AS ( 
  SELECT gid, ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS pt FROM river
), 
pts AS (
  SELECT gid, (pt).geom, (pt).path[1] AS vert FROM dumps
) 
SELECT a.gid as source_id, row_number() over() as gid, ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[a.geom, b.geom]) AS geom
FROM pts a, pts b 
WHERE a.gid = b.gid AND a.vert = b.vert-1 AND b.vert > 1;
```

`pgRouting` requires `source` and `target` columns to compute the toplogy.

```
ALTER TABLE river_segments ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS source integer;
ALTER TABLE river_segments ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS target integer;

SELECT pgr_createTopology('river_segments', 0.0001, 'geom', 'gid');
```

The function `pgr_createTopology` will add a new table named `river_segments_vertices_pgr` holding your graph nodes. Now you have everything you need to compute shortest paths between 2 points. The following common table expression selects a start and your destination point. These don't have to sit directly on the topology. When we invoke
`pgr_dijkstra` we tell PostGIS to find the nearest node as we limit it to 1. We do this for the source and destination point. Afterwards we join the shortest path results again with the river_segments table to obtain the geometries of the route. We stitch these together with `ST_Collect` and voila.

```sql
WITH start_point AS (
    SELECT geom from site
),
destination_point AS (
    SELECT geom from wwtp
    WHERE gid = 'WWTP1'
),
dijkstra AS (
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT gid as id, source, target, ST_Length(geom) AS cost FROM river_segments',
        -- finding the source node spatially
        (SELECT a.id FROM river_segments_vertices_pgr a, start_point b
            ORDER BY a.the_geom <-> b.geom LIMIT 1),
        -- finding the target node spatially
        (SELECT a.id FROM river_segments_vertices_pgr a, destination_point b
            ORDER BY a.the_geom <-> b.geom LIMIT 1),
        false
    )
),
route_geom AS (
    SELECT dijkstra.seq, dijkstra.cost,
    CASE
        WHEN dijkstra.node = river_segments.source THEN geom
        ELSE ST_Reverse(geom)
    END AS route_geom
    FROM dijkstra JOIN river_segments
    ON (edge = gid) ORDER BY seq
)
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Collect(route_geom)) FROM route_geom;
```

[image: routes with pgrouting]

Comment: This works for me, But how to implement 1 to many using this same data and query. what changes are to be made to get path to all destination points at once ? I need each destination path in a different row ?

Comment: @timothy-dalton I accepted my answer, since it leads to my intended result. +1 and thanks though, your code helped me a lot!